# Python, run exec() on a string 'return' to exit a function or thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading, execcommand

I would like to run exec() on 'return' in my function, so that my function returns and stops, here is my code:

```
def Function():#recieves time consuming function to do
    #checks if main thread should be closed, if so returns:
    return 'return "it worked"'
    #otherwise returns 'Null' so main thread keeps going

def MainThread():
    #Wants to do some function, so 
    exec(Function())
    return "didnt work"
```

when I run MainThread(), it says:

```
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

And I am not sure what is wrong there, I have simplified it and found that running exec('return') will also not work in a function.

Why I want to do this:
I have a thread that controls instruments, and before each command that it sends to the instruments I want it to check if it should abort, since controlling the instruments can be time consuming, and there are safety hazards. I don't want to copy-paste an if statement many times through my code, so thought of wrapping each command to an instrument with a check. 
It seems quite messy, if there are other approaches I would love to hear.
My current solution is:

```
def Function(stuff):#recieves time consuming function to do
#does things to stuff
return

def check(thing,skip):
    if skip==true:
        return
    else:
        Function(thing)
        return

def MainThread():
    skip = False #will be true or false if need to skip
    #Wants to do some function, so 
    check("the thing to do",skip)
```

If its necessary to abort the thread, it actually just skips through and does nothing at each function. At the end of the thread is aborts, but I didn't like simply keeping the thread there doing nothing and hoped for a better idea :)

Comment: That `return` is not indented correctly... That's why you get that error. Moreover, avoid using `exec` function (see [here](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/))

Comment: Ok thanks, there is an issue with the sample code, (trying to work out how to edit it) the top function should be un-indented. is that what you mean? because it still says return outside function.

Answer (score 1):

`exec()` does not execute the code in the context of the function in which it is called. The "`return "it worked"`" does not become a part of `Function()`, it is executed on it's own.